# responsive div element in html

Tags: html, wordpress, responsive-design

I want to put this in my static page, but also make it responsive
so far, I noticed when I make the browser small, the second div does not move to the bottom instead it is very squished to the side of the first one, how can I change that?

Here is my code:

```
<div style="float:left; height:200px;max-width:200px;width:100%;border:1px solid #000;padding:10px;">
<p><strong><span style="font-size:medium; color:#1A3A5C;">CFSRB: <br>Information Slider
</span></strong></p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mel partem delicata vituperata ei, patrioque incorrupte et sit. </div>
<div style="height:220px;border:1px solid #000;">
[insert picture here]
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `float:left`; to the second division will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Float both divs left. Reduce the width of the first div.

I made changes to your code:

```
<div style="float:left; height:200px;max-width:200px;width:50%;border:1px solid #000;padding:10px;">
<p><strong><span style="font-size:medium; color:#1A3A5C;">CFSRB: <br>Information Slider</span></strong></p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mel partem delicata vituperata ei, patrioque incorrupte et sit. </div>

<div style="float: left;width: auto; height:220px;border:1px solid #000;">
[insert picture here]
</div>
```

There is a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KP4sb/)